# I need a JavaScript RegEx to capture all words after a lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm really trying to understand RegEx and I feel like this issue should be easy and straightforward, but for some reason I'm really struggling to get exactly what I need. I've looked through at least 20 articles here and none of them are getting me there.

What I need is to capture all words after a lookbehind so I can count them. Here's what I've got so far:

RegEx: `/(?<=\> )(\w*)/gi`
String: `"Mon Jan 11 11:00 <ralph> Hello all!!"`

Capture all words after `"> "`, so in the above I only want the capture group to individually capture "Hello" and "all", so I can count the group and get the number words after the username, "<ralph>" in this example.

The above RegEx is just what I'm currently working with and it of course is only capturing the first word. I've also tried putting * and + after the capture group, but that nullifies the capture group for some reason.

I've also tried `(?<=\> )((\w*)(?:\W+))*`, and while this does match everything after the lookbehind, it only captures "all!!" and "all" in the 2 different captures. I'm not sure why "!!" is returning in any capture as I have it to match only with (?:).

Comment: Okay, how long will the names and what will the rules be for the names you have between < >?

Comment: `text.match(/(?<=> .*)\w+/g)` - see https://regex101.com/r/zMZ3aR/1

Comment: BGPHiJACK, the lookbehind is working fine, so the usernames are irrelevant. The words after the username can be any length within standard programmatic constraints.

Comment: @GregMohr There is no need to capture the `\w+`, as that is what is returned as the full match anyway. Regex functions in some languages do not support variable-width lookbehinds, e.g. PHP, so they will not accept the quantifier.

Comment: If you want to match only words and not cross other chars `(?<=> \s*(?:\w+\s+)*)\w+` https://regex101.com/r/ANmvJs/1

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, Thanks! That did the trick. Now I'm wondering why the .* in the lookbehind made such a difference. I tried a similar regex without the .* and it only gets the first word. I don't understand how the lookbehind is affecting the rest of the regex. regex101 complains about the quantifier in the lookbehind, but it's working in my IDE. Make this an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example

```js
const str = "Mon Jan 11 11:00 <ralph> Hello all. How are you?";

console.log( str.match(/(?<=\> (?:\w+\W+)*)\w+/g) );
```

> I'm not sure why "!!" is returning in any capture as I have it to match only with (?:).

Yes, but it is also captured by the first capture group. For example, if `"x"` is matched by `((?:x))`, then the first capture group will contain `"x"` even though it is also inside the second group which is non-capturing.

Comment: "Yes, but it is also captured by the first capture group". I don't understand why it would be. The example  is /(?<=\> )((\w*)(?:\W+))*/. The first capture group (I believe outer group) is composed of 1 capture group (group2) and 1 non-capture group. The capture group 2 is for 0 or more word characters (which ! doesn't belong to), so I'm not seeing where I'm specifying to capture !.

Comment: @GregMohr Non-capturing group don't cause a sequence to be excluded from other groups. They simply allow you do quantify a sequence without creating yet another group. In that regex, the non-capturing group is useless since there's no `|` inside it and no quantifier after it. "all!" is going to be returned as the full match and as capture group 1, while "all" is going to be in capture group 2.

Comment: @MikeM This is 3rd or 4th comment I've posted back to you, but I've deleted all the others as I've figured out what was confusing me soon after posting the comment. Let's hope the streak continues! :) The still confusing (to me) part of your regex, and similarly Wiktor's, is how the quantified part of the lookbehind is allowing for all words to be matched where as not quantifying it only finds the first match, even with global flag set. Any guidance you can give is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: @GregMohr If we use `(?<=> .*)\w+/g` to match `"<ralph> Hello you lot!"` then for the first match the `\w+` will match `"Hello"` and the lookbehind will match `"> "`, then for the second match the `\w+` will match `"you"` and the lookbehind will match `"> Hello "`, then for the third match the `\w+` will match `"lot"` and the lookbehind will match `"> Hello you "`. Do you understand now why the `*` quantifier is needed? Note also that one capturing group `()` can only return one string for each match object returned.

Answer (score 0):

`(?<=\> )(.+)` works fine for me it captures `Hello all!!` from `Mon Jan 11 11:00 <ralph> Hello all!!`
Is it what you need?

Comment: Nope. It's capturing it as 1 item. I need each word so I can count them programmatically.

Comment: Not a solution you want, but I would just run `.split(/\s+/)).length` and call it a day

Comment: Run a split removing spaces as suggested then and you will get each word between spaces inserted into an array to use. But pro-tip do a double space removal and convert it to single space first! If you don't you may have issues.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK `.split(/\s+/))` already removes multiple spaces

Comment: Konrad Linkowski, thanks, but part of the point is to use regex as it's WAY more efficient than built in string methods and I'm already using regex to capture the username.

Comment: @GregMohr do you have a benchmark comparing the two methods?

Comment: Konrad, they're pretty much all over the place. A quick search gave me the below, but there are plenty more. [link]https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/4781/0/split-vs-regex

Answer (score 0):

Is there a regular pattern after the `>` or it's random?

Anyway, this `(?<=\> )(.*)` matches your example.

Comment: Thanks, but nope, it's capturing it as a single string. I need individual words.